# How to send conditional response with ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make conditional `res.send` with `if/else` statement.

It works. However, after few second my server crash and i got this error

`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

I update my response so that it's looks like `return res.send...` But i'm still facing the same issue.

I really need to set my response conditionally and for my app logic i can't  set the response outside the `if/else`. Especially for synchronous purposes.

So how to prevent my server to crash ?

Exemple with firebase :

```js
if(req.body.hasOwnProperty('simplePost')){
      var postRef = admin.database().ref('post')
      postRef.once('value').then((snap)=>{
        if(!snap.exists()){
          return false
        }else{
          postRef.set(data)
          return res.status(200).end()
        }
      })
    }else if(req.body.hasOwnProperty('postWithRedirect')){
      var postRef = admin.database().ref('post')
      postRef.once('value').then((snap)=>{
        if(!snap.exists()){
          return false
        }else{
          postRef.set(data)
          return res.status(200)send({redirectUrl:snap.child('url').val()}).end()
        }
      })
    }
```

Comment: show us the code

Comment: Added some code. sorry

Comment: `return` inside a callback returns the callback function, not the surrounding one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Do you have two/more conditional branch that can execute in same flow? From the code shared, I don't see any problem as a response is sent only once for any given condition.

Comment: it's enough to use `return;` after `res.send()`